# When using multiple inner joins I get different results compared to when I use a single inner join

Tags: mysql, sql, select, inner-join, cartesian-product

I am having trouble understanding why my two SQL queries output different results for the count of senior managers when I expected them to be the same.

```
SELECT COMPANY.Company_Code, COMPANY.Founder, COUNT(SENIOR_MANAGER.Senior_Manager_Code)
FROM COMPANY INNER JOIN SENIOR_MANAGER
ON SENIOR_MANAGER.COMPANY_CODE = COMPANY.COMPANY_CODE
GROUP BY COMPANY.COMPANY_CODE, COMPANY.FOUNDER;
```

This SQL query is trying to find out how many senior managers there are in different companies, here are the results:

```
C1 Angela 5 
C10 Earl 2 
C100 Aaron 4 
C11 Robert 1 
C12 Amy 6
```

However, when I use the same condition in another query where I use two inner joins I get another set of results. Here is my query:

```
SELECT COMPANY.COMPANY_CODE, COMPANY.FOUNDER, COUNT(LEAD_MANAGER.LEAD_MANAGER_CODE), 
COUNT(SENIOR_MANAGER.SENIOR_MANAGER_CODE)
FROM COMPANY INNER JOIN LEAD_MANAGER
ON COMPANY.COMPANY_CODE = LEAD_MANAGER.COMPANY_CODE
INNER JOIN SENIOR_MANAGER
ON SENIOR_MANAGER.COMPANY_CODE = COMPANY.COMPANY_CODE
GROUP BY COMPANY.COMPANY_CODE, COMPANY.FOUNDER;
```

Here are the results:

```
C1 Angela 10 10 
C10 Earl 2 2 
C100 Aaron 8 8 
C11 Robert 1 1 
C12 Amy 12 12
```

The fourth column is the count of the senior managers & has the same values as the third column for some reason but has different values from the first query I showed. Can someone explain why the results are different I suspect it could be because I am using the inner joins incorrectly?

The desired result I expect is for the fourth column to have the values from the first query shown.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Two SQL LEFT JOINS produce incorrect result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12464037/two-sql-left-joins-produce-incorrect-result)

Comment: This seems a common error where people want some joins, each possibly involving a different key, of some subqueries, each possibly involving join and/or aggregation, but they erroneously try to do all the joining then all the aggregating or to aggregate over previous aggregations. Write separate aggregate subqueries over appropriate rows and/or aggregate (maybe distinct) case statements picking rows of (possibly join result) tables; then join the subqueries together. But one must pin down via a [mre] & write many clear, concise & precise phrasings of one's question/problem/goal to search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since counts of your two-join query reflects multiples of the one-join query, you are double counting the previously distinct pairings with new join.

Specifically, in first query `COMPANY` and `SENIOR_MANAGER` tables can have a one-to-many relationship where a distinct company can have multiple senior managers.

However, in second query when including `LEAD_MANAGER` table which would have even more distinct pairings to `COMPANY`, you repeat `SENIOR_MANAGER` multiple times for every corresponding pairing of `COMPANY` and `LEAD_MANAGER`.

---

As a solution to the double counting, consider joining aggregate subqueries (or [CTEs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/with.html)):

```sql
SELECT agg_s.COMPANY_CODE,
       agg_s.FOUNDER,
       agg_s.SENIOR_MANAGER_COUNT.
       agg_l.LEAD_MANAGER_COUNT
FROM
  (SELECT c.COMPANY_CODE, 
          c.FOUNDER, 
          COUNT(s.SENIOR_MANAGER_CODE) AS SENIOR_MANAGER_COUNT
   FROM COMPANY c
   INNER JOIN SENIOR_MANAGER s
      ON s.COMPANY_CODE = c.COMPANY_CODE
   GROUP BY c.COMPANY_CODE,
            c.FOUNDER
  ) AS agg_s
INNER JOIN
  (SELECT c.COMPANY_CODE, 
          c.FOUNDER, 
          COUNT(l.LEAD_MANAGER_CODE) AS LEAD_MANAGER_COUNT
   FROM COMPANY c
   INNER JOIN LEAD_MANAGER l
      ON c.COMPANY_CODE = l.COMPANY_CODE
   GROUP BY c.COMPANY_CODE,
            c.FOUNDER
  ) AS agg_l

ON  agg_s.COMPANY_CODE = agg_l.COMPANY_CODE
AND agg_s.FOUNDER = agg_l.FOUNDER
```

Even better, consider a table design change for proper normalization where you maintain a *single* `MANAGER` table with `TYPE` indicator column for `SENIOR` or `LEAD`. Then run a *single* query with conditional aggregation:

```sql
SELECT c.COMPANY_CODE, 
       c.FOUNDER, 
       COUNT(CASE WHEN m.TYPE = 'SENIOR' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS SENIOR_MANAGER_COUNT,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN m.TYPE = 'LEAD' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS LEAD_MANAGER_COUNT
FROM COMPANY c
INNER JOIN MANAGER m
   ON c.COMPANY_CODE = m.COMPANY_CODE
GROUP BY c.COMPANY_CODE,
         c.FOUNDER;
```

Answer (score 0):

Each time you join a new table, each row in the result set is multiplied by the number of times the join condition is matched in the new table for that row.

So your results show that each of C1, C100 and C12 has two LEAD_MANAGERs.